# Show that under suitable conditions we have $|Df(0)| + |Df(a)| \leq am.$

Tags: calculus

Prove the following:
Let $f$ be a function such that $D^{2}f$ is continuous on $[0, a],$ where $a > 0$ is given. If there is a real $m > 0$ such that $$|D^{2}f(x)| \leq m$$ for all $x \in [0, a]$ and if $\sup_{0 < x < a} f(x)$ exists, then 
$$|Df(0)| + |Df(a)| \leq am.$$

To prove it,
I made use of the given inequality to write
$$-m \leq D^{2}f(x) \leq m,$$
so that
$$\int_{0}^{a} -m dx \leq Df(x) + k \bigg|_{0}^{a} \leq \int_{0}^{a}m dx,$$
whence
$$|Df(a) - Df(0)| \leq am.$$
But it seems to me no way to go on?

Comment: Given $|f''(x)|\leq m$ you still can add an arbitrarily steep linear function to $f$ without changing $f''$. Therefore your claim cannot hold. – Maybe you have copied the problem wrong.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Thanks very much. I have posted an answer to my own question, please take a look at it if you would like to. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a proof. Note that since $\sup_{0 < x < a} f(x)$ exists, there is a real $0 < c < a$ such that
$$Df(c) = 0.$$
But
$$\int_{0}^{c}D^{2}f = Df(c) - Df(0) = -Df(0)$$
and
$$\int_{c}^{a}D^{2}f = Df(a) - Df(c) = Df(a),$$
so 
$$\big|Df(0)\big| + \big|Df(a)\big| = \bigg|\int_{0}^{c}D^{2}f\bigg| + \bigg|\int_{c}^{a}D^{2}f\bigg| \leq \int_{0}^{c}\big|D^{2}f\big| + \int_{c}^{a}\big|D^{2}f\big| \leq cm + am - cm = am.$$

I think the answer of @martini and the comment of @ChristianBlatter are a nice example showing that when the condition that $\sup_{0 < x < a}f(x)$ exists is dropped then we need not have the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is wrong. Let $f(x) = x^2 + x$ and $a = 1$. Then $f'(x) = 2x + 1$ and  $f''(x) = 2$, hence we can choose $m = 2$. We have
$$ |f'(0)| + |f'(1)| = 1 + 3 = 4 > 1 \cdot 2 = am $$

Comment: Many thanks for taking time to write! I guess that is because in this specific example the function $f$ takes on its greatest value at $a$, rather than somewhere between $0$ and $a$?

Comment: Thanks very much. I have posted an answer to my own question, please take a look at it if you would like to. :)